# Playframework [Scala]: Problems with i18n after migrating from 2.5 to 2.6

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5, playframework-2.6

I am working on migrating my project from play 2.5 to 2.6.
Everything seems ok, however, there is a problem with i18n in within my views,  rendered by scala controllers(and there is no such problem with java controllers).

To provide i18n, `play.api.i18n.Messages.apply` method is used in both cases, but with Scala controller(derived from `AbstractController` or `InjectedController`) there are only marks from `Messages.lang` file, not values.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `controller` class:

1. Inject controller components and the actor system
2. Use the implicit value of assets finder.
3. Extending it with `AbstractController` and `I18nSupport`:

   ```
   class myController @Inject()
    (controllerComponents: ControllerComponents,actorSystem: ActorSystem)
    (implicit assetsFinder: AssetsFinder) 
    extends AbstractController(cc) with I18nSupport{ 
    ??? //Body of your controller class. 
   }
   ```

In your `views`:

Within your views file use three implicit values of `RequestHeader`, `Messages`, and `AssetsFinder`:

```
@(whatever: Any)(implicit req: RequestHeader, messages: Messages, assetsFinder: AssetsFinder)
```